# JAVA: Substitute for a break statement?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, break

For some ridiculous reason my professor has prohibited us from using break statements in our programs to terminate loops. I am making a Connect Four program and am using for loops to simulate the player dropping a checker. If my loops look like this:

```
for(int i = LOWEST_ROW_INDEX; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(gb[i][rChoice].equals(". "))
        {
            gb[i][rChoice] = "r ";
            break; //CANNOT USE BREAK
        }
    }
```

What could I do instead of a break statement to terminate this for loop?

Comment: When does a loop end?

Comment: Add another condition to the for loop. `for (int i = LOWEST_ROW_INDEX; i >=0, someBoolean; i--)` Then in your body set `someBoolean = false` when you want to break.

Answer (score 3):

You could cheat a little bit:

```
i = -1;
```

Comment: this would not be cheating. In this example `i` is declared inside the for loop and it has no scope outside it. So setting it to `-1` will not have side effects. So this is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

It's not sooo ridiculous. Some purists consider `break` as being evil - similar to "mutliple `return` statements", but not as much as "`break` with label" or `goto`. A program with nested loops and some `break` statements can be rather confusing.

Another possible solution here would be something like this:

```
private int findInsertionIndex()
{
    for(int i = LOWEST_ROW_INDEX; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(gb[i][rChoice].equals(". "))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Use
int insertionIndex = findInsertionIndex();
if (insertionIndex != -1)
{
    gb[insertionIndex][rChoice] = "r ";
}
```

(Yes, I know that I traded a `break` against a method with "multiple returns". Sometimes it's all about playing the game. I think the code snippet already shows some practices that one could consider as worse than a `break`. For example, odd variable names, global variables and a 2D array of Strings...)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to `while`

```
int i = LOWEST_ROW_INDEX;
while(!gb[i][rChoice].equals(". ") && i >=0 ){
  i--;
}
if (i >= 0){
  gb[i][rChoice] = "r ";
}
```